# How to determine where debian package was sourced

Tags: debian

How would I trace out which archive(s) in the sources.list a given installed deb package was or (could be) sourced from?   I understand that the same package may be indexed by multiple archives.

Does "aptitude" log any of this type of information when its installing packages?

My aim is to pare down my current sources.list to the minimum set of archives needed to maintain the current set of installed packages.

Answer (score 4):

- You can use `apt-cache policy <package>` to find out where a package originated from.
- Combined with `apt-cache pkgnames` you should be able to find out which sources you are using.

Answer (score 0):

In aptitude, select the binary package by hi lighting it then hitting ENTER, then look for the `Source Package:` line.